# Error message undefined email while logging through Facebook API in laravel 4

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-4, facebook-javascript-sdk, laravel-routing

Giving error message undefined email.AS well as when I want to insert lastname giving same error undefined lastname.

Please help me out.First time I am implementing API in laravel.

Please send me any link related to Facebook and google login in laravel 4.2

```
 Route::get('login/fb', function(){ $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$params = array(
    'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'),
    'scope' => 'email',
);
return Redirect::away($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));});
```

<----------------------------------------------------------------------------->

```
Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {


$code = Input::get('code');

if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

$me = $facebook->api('/me');


$profile = Profile::whereUid($uid)->first();
if (empty($profile)) {

    $user = new User;
   $user->firstname = $me['name'];
    $user->email=$me['email'];

    $user->pic = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$me['id'].'/picture?type=large';

    $user->save();

    $profile = new Profile();
    $profile->uid = $uid;
    $profile->username = $me['id'];
    $profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);
}

$profile->access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$profile->save();

$user = $profile->user;

Auth::login($user);

return Redirect::to('index')->with('message', 'Logged in with Facebook');
```

});

Comment: are you getting `$me` correctly?

Comment: Yes I am getting my $me correctly

Comment: $me = $facebook->api('/me');

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly requests fields you need:

> $me = $facebook->api('/me?fields=email,last_name,first_name');

Comment: Because i used Facebook connect for a Javascript application and I had the same issue. The scope I used: "public_profile,email" and to get the user email : FB.api('/me?fields=email', function (response) { var email = response.email; });